# Linq return current rows where the next row has value

Tags: c#, linq

I need to process an invoice which is given to me as a single Excel column of strings, which I have converted to a `List<string>`. A simplified sample looks like this.

```
This is a nothing line
No001 FOO67 368.80
No001 FOO67 17.68
SHORT 12345
```

In this example, I might need to extract data from each line that begins with "No" - the Reference (e.g. FOO67) and amount (e.g. 368.80). However, if I encounter a line that starts with "SHORT", that means that the previous line amount was really an adjustment and the reference should be whatever I find on the "SHORT" line, with the sign of the amount reversed. In the case above, the data I hope to extract would be as follows (the first line is column headings):

```
Reference    Amount
  FOO67      368.80
  12345      -17.68
```

I cannot find any way to achieve this using a linq query against the list. A mock-up of what I think a solution might look like is this (the below will not parse as I have added "nextline" as a pseudocode addition):

```
var inv = new List<string> { "This is a nothing line", "No001 FOO67 368.80", "No001 FOO67 17.68", "SHORT 123456" };

var myTable = new DataTable();

myTable.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int));
myTable.Columns.Add("Ref", typeof(string));
myTable.Columns.Add("Amount", typeof(double));

var foo = from l in inv
            where (l.Substring(0, 2) == "No" && double.TryParse(l.Split(' ')[2], out i))
            select myTable.LoadDataRow(new object[]
                    { inv.IndexOf(l)
                     ,nextline.Contains("SHORT")? nextline.Split(' ')[1] : l.Split(' ')[1]
                     ,nextline.Contains("SHORT")? -1:1 * double.Parse(l.Split(' ')[2].Replace(",", "").Replace("-", ""))
                    }, LoadOption.OverwriteChanges);
```

Is there a known way to get the value from the next line of a query and use it to decide which rows to return? If so, what is the way to do it?

Comment: You could probably make use of Skip() and Take() but I don't think what you are asking would come out of the box for Linq

Comment: I wondered about making two datasets, with the second offset from the first by one row and then comparing the two, joined on an index - maybe that's the best way to go? I don't want to go miles around the houses if there is a fairly simple solution

Comment: The best way to go is to **not** use LINQ - it's not suited for such tasks. Simple `for` loop will do it quite easily.

Comment: I agree with @IvanStoev. You have to combine the values from different iteration steps. This is quite hard in LINQ. Maybe write an LINQ extension method that uses `foreach` and `yield return`. That's much easier.

Comment: Any feedback to accompany the downvote would be gratefully received - I cannot correct incorrect behaviour without an indication of the error...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like following.

```
var inv = new List<string> 
                { 
                 "This is a nothing line", 
                 "No001 FOO67 368.80", 
                 "No001 FOO67 17.68", 
                 "SHORT 123456" 
                };

var filterValidLines = inv.ToLookup(c=>c.StartsWith("No") 
                                              ||c.StartsWith("SHORT"));
var result = filterValidLines[true].Zip(
                            filterValidLines[true].Skip(1),
                            (x,y)=>
{ 
    var subData= x.Split(new []{" "},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    var multiplier = y.StartsWith("SHORT")? -1:1;
    return new Data{Reference= subData[1], Amount = double.Parse(subData[2]) * multiplier};
});
```

Output

```
Reference Amount
FOO67     368.8 
FOO67     -17.68
```

Comment: While this does not quite return the data i wanted, I have been able to use your suggestion (specifically `IEnumerable.Zip()` combined with `IEnumerable.Skip()` to return what I want. Should I add my actual solution onto your answer and mark it as the answer, or would you rather I make a new answer (or something else)?

Answer (score 1):

A quick and dirty solution:

```
void Main()
{
    var list = new List<string>
    {
        "This is a nothing line",
        "No001 FOO67 368.80",
        "No001 FOO67 17.68",
        "SHORT 12345"
    };


    var invoices = list
        .Select((l, i) => new InvoiceData
        { 
            Line = l, 
            NextLine = i < list.Count - 1 ? list[i + 1] : string.Empty 
        })
        .Where(x => x.Line.StartsWith("No"))
        .ToList();
}

public class InvoiceData
{
    public string Line { get; set; }
    public string NextLine { get; set; }
    public bool IsAdjustment => NextLine.StartsWith("SHORT");
    public decimal Amount =>
        IsAdjustment 
            ? -decimal.Parse(Line.Split(' ')[2])
            : decimal.Parse(Line.Split(' ')[2]);
    public string Reference =>
        IsAdjustment
            ? NextLine.Split(' ')[1]
            : Line.Split(' ')[1];
}
```